# JavaScript is there a way to stop href="#" to refresh a page ? nyroModal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nyromodal

Is there some script that can stop `<herf="#">` from refreshing a page?

You might ask why I would do that? Well I am enhancing an old .net web project,
it uses nyroModal jQuery to open up a lightbox with, but when I try to close up the lightbox, nyroModal applies a hash (i.e. `#`) at the end of the URL and cause the page to refresh, which causes the screen to flip (bad user experience)

#### Javascript code:

```
$(function () {
    //set up light box
    var width = 766;
    var height = 591;
    $('.nyroModal').nyroModal({
        sizes: {
            initW: width, initH: height,
            minW: width, minH: height,
            w: width, h: height
        },
        callbacks: {
            beforeShowCont: function () {
               =$('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
               =//width = $('.nyroModalCont').width();
               =//height = $('.nyroModalCont').height();
               =$('.nyroModalCont').css('width', width);
               =$('.nyroModalCont').css('height', height);
               =$('.nyroModalCont iframe').css('width', width);
               =$('.nyroModalCont iframe').css('height', height);
            =},
            =afterResize: function () {
               $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            },
            afterShowCont: function () {
               $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            },
            afterClose: function () {
               $('html').css('overflow', 'auto');
               //resizeBackground();
            }
         }
     });
 });
```

It would be great if anyone can show me how to solve this refreshing problem with a hash at the end of the URL. Or after refresh, my screen position stay the same. Not going up or down many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my projects, I add this code to prevent the jerk ( as the page scrolls to top ) when an anchor with `href=#` is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[href=#]").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });//a[href=#] click
});//document ready
```

This way you need not go to every anchor tag and disable this. In case, there are some exceptional anchor tags, you can easily exclude those using some selector or adding some condition inside this click handler.

And if you don't want this behaviour, you can directly remove these lines from your javascript, there is no need to modify your html code.

Comment: Thank you so much this works for me, and the code you provided give me a lot more control over the project. you just saved my life. ^^

Comment: @Sameul.T Happy to know it was helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">Link</a>
```

This will prevent your page reloading.

Answer (score 1):

Put `javascript:void(0)` in href like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">Anchor</a>
```

and try again.

Answer (score 1):

when you write `href="#"` then it search the id that given with `#id`.

Below code is work on current page and use to run javascript function.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="function()">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by CSS

```css
    .notActive {
       pointer-events: none;
       cursor: default;
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="notActive"> Disabled link </a>
```

Comment: If it is ok, then you can give me an upvote mate. @Sameul.T

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this would be to prevent action if anchor consist '#' alone. 
Great. Here you go:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').on('click',function(e){
        // Explicit check
                // $(e.target).is('a')
            if($(e.target).attr('href').lastIndexOf('#')!=-1){
                     e.preventDefault();
                }
    });
});
```

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/Ashokkumargupta/5rs4621w/

Note: Benefit with above code is to avoid accidental links which also have "target" attribute by default.

Hope this helps!

Thanks,

Ashok